# Download speed from server extremely slow

Tags: linux, debian

I have rented many servers @server4you and from time to I face the same problem. Download speed from a server decreases dramatically and after some weeks goes back to normal.

Now when I download a file from my Debian server, the speed is only 400-500 kbps.It's not my Internet connection problem. I tested it by downloading a file to anoher server in another data center. The same results.

There are no other problems with this server. The load is under 1, I have not installed any new software (only automatic updates).

Any ideas how to find out what can cause this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of possible causes of the problem - the most likely being bottlnecks between providers, or between points of presence in a providers network.

There are a number of tools which can help with diagnosing the problems, but no single bullet.   The easiest tool to use is MTR, which combines traceroute and ping to show latencies and packet loss.   Its important to look at packet loss as it is very often associated with slowdowns - in fact the tcp protocol is built on the assumption that if the network is to slow it should discard the packet as a hint to slow down transmission.

(On the flip side of using MTR, it is possible to prioritise traffic to fool it - and not even deliberately sometimes - for example routers are better at forwarding packets then answering them.)    That said, something like MTR is a very good tool.

The next tool to look at is something like iperf. This does bandwidth testing.  It may be useful to know what happens with multiple concurrant connections - There is a loose correlation between the increases of total speed of concurrent connections and congestion - however latencies and distances also play a role.

You may also want to look at how busy your server is, If they are linux boxes, iptraf is a text base interface which can be useful, and is easy to run.   There are plenty of other tools you could use as well.

Also, a note that the "load" does not neccessarily tell you anything about how loaded the system is - it is only a summary of the number of tasks waiting to be be handled.   Its not useless, but it is entirely possible to see extremely high loads (hundreds) and still have great performance - depending on a number of factors - including bandwidth constraints, but also disk waits and simultaneous processes.   Running programs like vmstat or iotop may give you better insites into what is going on.

Lastly, you talked about "a machine".  Is this a real machine or a VM ?  Its possible for a VM to look OK, but be constrained by overprovisioning / underperformance of the host.

Comment: davidgo, its a dedicated server, not a VM. MTR and Iperf don't show any problems. Peple from DC today checked my server. They confirmed that download speed is very low, however, they can not help because they "don't see any issues" on the server/network. This morning download speed was about 30k/s. A couple of years ago I had the same problem with another server @server4you. Then the problem disappeared itself after 2-3 weeks.

Comment: If what you have said about the problem disappearing after 2-3 weeks is true the issue is most likely with your provider, but there are a couple of possibilities on your end/possible mitigations you may want to follow up - The first is MTU clamping. Try the command "iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu"   which might fix TCP connections if your ISP is running an MTU lower then yours - if this works you may want to try removing the line and setting a lower MTU on your device.  The other thing to look at is the network card - can you advise what it is?

Comment: The oher thing to look at is your Network card - many Realtek network cards, for example are not good at handling large volumes of traffic, and have multiple drivers which give very differing performance.  See if rebooting your system helps initially, and possibly try a different network card - I would suggest Intel cards for compatibility, speed and ease of getting to work.

Answer (score 0):

Monitor the connection using mtr, smokeping or similar tools, use iftop or nethogs to find applications that use bandwidth.
Is the transferred data encrypted?